# Hide general and shipping details when adding a new order in Woocommerce admin

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, backend

In the admin page when you press "add new order" there is General Details, Billing Details and Shipping Details:

[image: Picture here]

I would love to hide some these with CSS. I've tried all day but have been able to achieve this unsuccessfully.

I just want to keep the **Billing details** visible. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply with the following hooked function and some specific CSS rules:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_admin_head');
function my_admin_head() {
    ?>
    <style>
    .post-new-php.post-type-shop_order #postbox-container-2 .order_data_column_container > .order_data_column:first-child,
    .post-new-php.post-type-shop_order #postbox-container-2 .order_data_column_container > .order_data_column:last-child {
        display:none !important;
    }
    </style>
<?php
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works…